# Navigator Invariant Violation: onlyChild must be passed children with exactly one child

Tags: react-native

I have an error when i use Navigator and TouchableHighlight in my app
this is the code for my index.ios.js (render and renderScene functions):

```
      render: function() {

        return (
          <View>
          <Navigator
           renderScene={this.renderScene}>
          </Navigator>
          </View>
       )
      },

     renderScene: function(route, nav) {
          return <LoginView navigator={nav} />;
     }
```

and this is the code for the LoginView

```
    var LoginView = React.createClass({
      onPress: function() {

      },
      render: function() {

        return (

            <View>
              <TouchableHighlight />
            </View>

        )
      },
    });
```

I'm sure this happens because of the fact that TouchableHighlight can only have one child (in the render function of TouchableHihglight.js there is a use of the onlyChild function from onlyChild.js to verify the number of children)
What I do not understand is why in my case TouchableHighlight has more than one child (as I see it there are no children at all)???

hope you help me guys (:

Comment: Are you passing in an empty TouchableHighlight ? If so, why? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah you right, it was my bad. I just needed to add any child to the TouchableHighlight

Comment: Ok great, I'll go ahead and put the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass in one child to TouchableHighlight. Something like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Will eliminate the error.